Melting multiple columns in Python Panda
Melting multiple columns in Python Panda
Hello all,
I stack in this coding for two day. I want to get a proper df for EDA and then machine learning. I am new to Python. Could you help?
My data
enter image description here
After pivot
enter image description here
tourism5 = tourism4.pivot_table(index=["Year"], columns=["Tourists to Ireland", "Area of Residence"], values="VALUE")

tourism5

tourism6 = tourism5.melt(id_vars=["Year"], var_name= ["Average Stay Nights", "Tourists Expenditure", "Tourists Number"],value_name="VALUE")

tourism6

I try to melt it. But, it keeps giving error message.
Thanks for your help in advance.
File C:\Users\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\melt.py:74, in melt(frame, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)70 if missing.any():71     missing_labels = [72         lab for lab, not_found in zip(labels, missing) if not_found73     ]---> 74     raise KeyError(75         "The following id_vars or value_vars are not present in "76         f"the DataFrame: {missing_labels}"77     )78 if value_vars_was_not_none:79     frame = frame.iloc[:, algos.unique(idx)]

KeyError: "The following id_vars or value_vars are not present in the DataFrame: ['Year']"


It seems to me that melting tourism5 would result in a table of similar structure to tourism4. Could you clarify what structure you would like tourism6 to have?

Please do not upload images of code / data / errors. Please do offer a reprex.

@ sillycone , Hi, via some kind of machine learning (not sure, as I am new to this (: ), I want to do prediction of Tourists to Ireland (includes Tourists Number, Average Stay Nights, Tourists Expenditure) by Area of Residence (includes different countries). When I tried to pivot by Tourists to Ireland and Area of Residence, the VALUES of columns changes (incorrect compare to the original data.)    Could you advice?
